# Javascript object is got deleted strangely

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, gantt-chart

I runned the below-given code using `$(document).ready()`. The problem is that CATCH was executed and the `err.message` returned **g is not defined**. But `alert(g)` returned **object Object**. I don't understand why the object **g** was deleted so strangely. Please help.

http://jsfiddle.net/Udkkv/4/

```
 <script>
function createChartControl(htmlDiv) {
      var g = new JSGantt.GanttChart('g',document.getElementById(htmlDiv), 'day');

        g.setShowRes(1); // Show/Hide Responsible (0/1)
        g.setShowDur(1); // Show/Hide Duration (0/1)
        g.setShowComp(1); // Show/Hide % Complete(0/1)
       g.setCaptionType('Resource');  // Set to Show Caption (None,Caption,Resource,Duration,Complete)

        // Parameters             (pID, pName,                  pStart,      pEnd,        pColor,   pLink,          pMile, pRes,  pComp, pGroup, pParent, pOpen, pDepend, pCaption)

        g.AddTaskItem(new JSGantt.TaskItem(1,   'Define Chart API',     '',          '',          'ff0000', 'http://help.com', 0, 'Brian',     0, 1, 0, 1));
        g.AddTaskItem(new JSGantt.TaskItem(11,  'Chart Object',         '7/20/2008', '7/20/2008', 'ff00ff', 'http://www.yahoo.com', 1, 'Shlomy',  100, 0, 1, 1));
        g.AddTaskItem(new JSGantt.TaskItem(12,  'Task Objects',         '',          '',          '00ff00', '', 0, 'Shlomy',   40, 1, 1, 1));
        g.AddTaskItem(new JSGantt.TaskItem(121, 'Constructor Proc',     '7/21/2008', '8/9/2008',  '00ffff', 'http://www.yahoo.com', 0, 'Brian T.', 60, 0, 12, 1));
        g.AddTaskItem(new JSGantt.TaskItem(122, 'Task Variables',       '8/6/2008',  '8/11/2008', 'ff0000', 'http://help.com', 0, 'Brian',         60, 0, 12, 1,121));
        g.AddTaskItem(new JSGantt.TaskItem(123, 'Task by Minute/Hour',       '8/6/2008',  '8/11/2008 12:00', 'ffff00', 'http://help.com', 0, 'Ilan',         60, 0, 12, 1,121));
        g.AddTaskItem(new JSGantt.TaskItem(124, 'Task Functions',       '8/9/2008',  '8/29/2008', 'ff0000', 'http://help.com', 0, 'Anyone',   60, 0, 12, 1, 0, 'This is another caption'));
        g.AddTaskItem(new JSGantt.TaskItem(2,   'Create HTML Shell',    '8/24/2008', '8/25/2008', 'ffff00', 'http://help.com', 0, 'Brian',    20, 0, 0, 1,122)); 

        g.Draw();   
        g.DrawDependencies();

      }

}
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {             
   createChartControl('schedule');
});

<div style="position:relative" class="gantt" id="schedule"></div>
```

**UPDATE:** I should say that if I run this code without $(document).ready() - i.e. right after DIV tags, then it works. How could it be???

**UPDATE 2:** Here is reproduced project: http://jsfiddle.net/Udkkv/4/ It's not working, but maybe now it will be easier to help.

Comment: Try stepping through the try block to see what which reerence fails

Comment: @YouKuper have you tried `alert(JSON.stringify(g));` or `console.log(g);`? Those will produce the exact object contents.

Comment: get rid of the try catch and see what's causing it to fail?

Comment: console.log(g) returned something like Object { setFormatArr=function(), setShowRes=function(), setShowDur=function()... So, it's not null

Comment: This is your actual code? Or is it a "simplified" version? What you're describing doesn't make sense. If it makes it through the `if (g)` part, and if `alert(g)` shows `[object Object]`, then there's no reason to get a `g is not defined` error.

Comment: ...unless there's a different `g` variable in one of the functions you're invoking in the `try/catch`. If there is, rename it so that you can tell the variables apart.

Comment: I deleted 'if'. Anyway, Firebug says that the line 'g.AddTaskItem()' failed. It's strange because I'm using sample code of jsgantt's developers. Also, I should say that if I run this code without $(document).ready() - i.e. right after DIV tags, then it works. How could it be???

Comment: So is Firebug  telling you `g` isn't defined, or is it telling you `g.AddTaskItem` isn't a function?

Comment: I just looked at http://www.jsgantt.com/docs/JSGantt.TaskItem.html.  It has 14 parameters while you are passing in only 12.  Not sure if that's the issue though.

Comment: @wirey: That's a good point. I should check it, though I used demo code of developers. But in any case this code is working without $(document).ready() and it's really strange.

Comment: Please paste code that calls this function. I suspect the problem is there.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: I placed the complete code.

Comment: @wirey: I checked, it was not the issue of 14 parameters. Not all parameters are mandatory.

Comment: What version of jQuery and what browser? I've seen jQuery 1.8 firing the DOM ready handler too early on IE9 (and 1.7.2 is reported to fire it earlier on IE8). To be safe, I put my scripts at the very end of the `body` as suggested in [Crockford's best practices](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/24-javascript-best-practices-for-beginners/). This way, having a DOM ready handler or not doesn't make much difference, but I still use it to have a closure.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: I'm using jQuery 1.7.2, Firefox and Chrome. Do you suggest to use newer versions of jQuery?

Comment: It has some glitches with the UI and I wouldn't upgrade unless you want to spend some time testing your code to make it didn't break anything (but if your code isn't working atm, you might try to upgrade but your problem is unrelated to the jQuery version IMO).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: I placed scripts after DIV container, but I still use $(document).ready(). Does not work so far. Is it possible to replace $(document).ready() with sth else to initiate the function?

Comment: Tha's weird man, if the script is after the `div` it must work. Unless there's a bug with the `JSGantt` or in your code. Maybe trying to reproduce it on a http://jsfiddle.net/ may help debugging.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Here is reproduced project: http://jsfiddle.net/Udkkv/4/ It's not working, but maybe now it will be easier to help.

Comment: There was one syntax error in the fiddle, but that's not your problem.. Weird, it should work. I commented the line that returns an error http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/Udkkv/6/

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Thanks for your help. At least I know it's most probably some bug of jsgantt.

Comment: Yup, I tried to reproduce their example code in the home page, no luck either.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: For me it worked only when I did not use the function createChartControl and placed the script after DIV container ( without $(document).ready() )

Comment: Yup I see, I tried placing it without the ready handler and it almost works: http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/Udkkv/7/ there are still errors in the console though. Seems like there are some bugs or there's something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The var g is used before it is defined. The problem lies within the .js file from your website: "http://www.jsgantt.com/jsgantt.js".

```
if (vGroup != 1)
  {  
     vStart = JSGantt.parseDateStr(pStart,g.getDateInputFormat());
     vEnd   = JSGantt.parseDateStr(pEnd,g.getDateInputFormat());
  }
```

In the above code you are trying to use:

```
g.getDateInputFormat()
```

while var g is still not defined.

Comment: So, how to solve this problem? Could you please propose your solution in my jsfiddle example? Thanks.